# How to check if content is loaded in HTML embed tag?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I am using embed tag to load pdf. It's a legacy application so can't use other approach. I want to run some javascript function when pdf loads completely in embed tag. How can I do this?

I have tried using onload event on embed tag but it doesn't work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //This function should be called when pdf loads.
        function ContentLoaded()
        {
            //Some code which should execute only after PDF loads on browser
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <embed  id="content" src="myfile.pdf"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to place `<script>` tag just before the closing body tag (`</body>`). This way, JS code will run after the HTML content loaded.

If you place the code below before the closing head tag (`</head>`), it shows you error in developer's console. But if you place it before `</body>` tag, it works just fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pdf = document.getElementById('content');
  console.log('pdf:', pdf);

  var w = pdf.getAttribute('width');
  console.log('pdf width is exactly:', w, 'pixels');
</script>
```